# SQL Server : Unique constraint to verify that data does not exist in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, unique-constraint

Given that I have a table structure where I have a parent that can have "Roles" and that parent have children that can have the same "Roles", how can I create a constraint on the child table that verifies that the parent does not have the Role that is about to be inserted?

Like this:

```
Parent
 |
 \- ParentRoles
 |
 \- Child
    |
    \- ChildRoles
```

I want the union of the Child and Parent roles to be a list of unique roles (no duplicates).

I have checked [Constraint by UserFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200795/sql-server-check-constraint-on-a-column-where-values-come-from-another-table) (not recommended but would work) and tried creating a view with an unique index but ran into trouble because I have to use Union in the view and then I cannot index it.

An answer on the [Constraint by UserFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200795/sql-server-check-constraint-on-a-column-where-values-come-from-another-table) question suggests using Foreign Keys but I do not understand how I could make that work given my table structure.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I create a constraint on the child table that verifies that the parent does not have 
>   the Role that is about to be inserted?

You can not - constraints can not easily o that. I would go with a trigger.

Comment: Constraint does not absolutely have to mean the SQL Server Constraint, it could be any form of database functionality. I just want the database to ensure that inserted data is correct.

Comment: Well, you know the word "context"? "Limit data in sql server in a constraint" means quite brutally a sql server constraint. Anyhow, just use a trigger.